# ViewPager and Fragments - java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value MyFragment{af26794 #1 id=0x7f0e0120}

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am getting a crash whenever I leave my fragment with a `ViewPager` either by pressing the home button or starting a new activity. I believe this is related to having `onPause` being called because if I leave the activity.

**Has anyone else experienced this issue with `ViewPagers` and `Fragments`?**

I saw another thread where the guy just set his Fragments as `Serializable`, but that seems a bit hacky to me?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.myapp.myapp, PID: 16504
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value MyFragment{4f941f6 #1 id=0x7f0e0120}
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1418)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:662)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:646)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1336)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686)
                                                                               at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
                                                                               at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:138)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1254)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:385)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1437)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1343)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686)
                                                                               at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
                                                                               at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3152)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3417)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Fragment with ViewPager

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/quiz_accent_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_current_question"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/content_padding_half"
            android:textSize="@dimen/profile_text_normal"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_time_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="@dimen/content_padding_half"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/profile_text_normal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/gray_horizontal_divider_view"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your actual code, it seems like you're trying to store / retrieve an instance of Fragment from a Parcel?  That's definitely not something you should be doing for a number of reasons, even if you do make your Fragment implement Serializable, as any listeners, callbacks etc. that you had hooked up in the Fragment will be invalid.

There are a number of scenarios where you might be trying to do this but in your case it looks like from the stack trace this may be happening as a result of onSaveInstanceState.

Instead of trying to store the entire Fragment instance, you should only persist key Serializable / Parcelable members of the Fragment necessary to represent the state of the Fragment in onSaveInstanseState.  Then, restore those state variables in your Fragment's onCreate.

Comment: You are absolutely right, in my Fragment I am storing the instances of the Fragments that are in my ViewPager. I did this basically because of a callback from a dialog that is shown from one of the ViewPager fragments and it is calling back to the Activity, which then passes the info to the fragment. Need to change this roundabout logic. But now I understand why, thanks!